# PTIJ: Can I use my cattle prod to get people to minyan?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

If I leave an electric cattle prod on from before Shabbos, may I use it to coax Jews (gently) to come to minyan?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I don't see how this qualifies as PTIJ under the policy. Take away the disclaimer and you have perfectly serious looking question

Comment: @DoubleAA I then have a lot of other questions, but, technically, yes.

Comment: Definitely does not have a serious answer and seems to be PTIJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Lichorah* the *chakirah* is as follows:

Let's say it is permissible to use an electronic device on Shabbat where the device is always on, and you only modulate the amount of current flowing by using it, and there is no *hashma'as kol* (so for example, the United Synagogue Bet Din allows the *chazan* to sing into a microphone that feeds into an induction loop that goes round the synagogue for people with hearing aids).

Then the question is:

When I prod the *mitpallel* with my cattle-prod, am I creating a new circuit because electricity goes from prod to ground through congregant (forbidden - because we now have a new circuit and therefore I have done a *melacha* of *boneh*) or am I simply modulating the amount of current going through the prod (permissible - as above).

The answer appears to depend on the spiritual level of the congregant.

If the congregant is on a high spiritual level and far away from *artziyut* then we cannot consider him as a ground and it is permissible. However if the congregant is close to *artziut* then he is a good ground and it is forbidden.

From which we see that *be'derech she'adam rotzeh le'lech molichin oto*.